# Problems with CLR wrapping of C++ DirectX project using Windows API

Tags: c++, clr

Ok, so I have a project that I'm trying to create a wrapper for that will allow me to use it with the CLR.

I've compiled my DirectX project into a .lib. When I try and link that in my CLR project, I'm getting the following errors:

```
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxW@16 referenced in function __catch$?SetUpObjects@cMain@@AAE_NXZ$0
1>Renderer Library.lib(cGraphics.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxW@16
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ShowCursor@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::InitializeWindows(int &,int &)" (?InitializeWindows@cMain@@AAEXAAH0@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetFocus@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::InitializeWindows(int &,int &)" (?InitializeWindows@cMain@@AAEXAAH0@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetForegroundWindow@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::InitializeWindows(int &,int &)" (?InitializeWindows@cMain@@AAEXAAH0@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ShowWindow@8 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::InitializeWindows(int &,int &)" (?InitializeWindows@cMain@@AAEXAAH0@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateWindowExW@48 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::InitializeWindows(int &,int &)" (?InitializeWindows@cMain@@AAEXAAH0@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ChangeDisplaySettingsW@8 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::InitializeWindows(int &,int &)" (?InitializeWindows@cMain@@AAEXAAH0@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetSystemMetrics@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::InitializeWindows(int &,int &)" (?InitializeWindows@cMain@@AAEXAAH0@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegisterClassExW@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::InitializeWindows(int &,int &)" (?InitializeWindows@cMain@@AAEXAAH0@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetStockObject@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::InitializeWindows(int &,int &)" (?InitializeWindows@cMain@@AAEXAAH0@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__LoadCursorW@8 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::InitializeWindows(int &,int &)" (?InitializeWindows@cMain@@AAEXAAH0@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__LoadIconW@8 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::InitializeWindows(int &,int &)" (?InitializeWindows@cMain@@AAEXAAH0@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__UnregisterClassW@8 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::ShutdownWindows(void)" (?ShutdownWindows@cMain@@AAEXXZ)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DestroyWindow@4 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cMain::ShutdownWindows(void)" (?ShutdownWindows@cMain@@AAEXXZ)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DefWindowProcW@16 referenced in function "public: long __stdcall cMain::MessageHandler(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?MessageHandler@cMain@@QAGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
1>Renderer Library.lib(cMain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PostQuitMessage@4 referenced in function "long __stdcall WndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WndProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
```

I'm trying to create a window for rendering in, but all the functions I have to call to do that don't appear to work.

Eventually I want to restructure my DirectX project in a way that allows me to utilise it in the way I want with the CLR. At the moment though, I'm just trying to get it to play nice. The problem appears to be functions I'm using to create a window and initialize my DirectX device. Not really sure how to remedy it, whether it's just something I've missed linker wise or whether I should be employing a different strategy.

Comment: Guessing at VS2008.  Right-click your project, Properties, Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies.  Delete "$(NoInherit)" so that you'll link user32.lib

Comment: VS2010, does that change anything?

Comment: The entry you mentioned wasn't there, but adding two lines #pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib") and #pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib") appears to have fixed the problem, so thanks for pointing this out to me.